# PHP - User Profile with multiple different file inputs

Tags: php, file, upload

So I have searched a lot about this, but can't find any good answer.
I have a hrm, where I add Users and each of them has their info like name, age, address, etc etc.
I also add couple of files, like: image, ID card (jpg/pdf), Tax card (pdf), Agreement document (pdf) and there are couple of more.

Each of these documents have their seperate input field, and each will be uploaded in a different folder on the server. I got it working, but I am not sure if my method is the right way:

**Basic Info (there are lot of inputs here so I won't list them all):**

```
    if(isset($_POST['btnsave'])){

    $id  = $_POST['w_rid'];
    $name  = $_POST['w_name'];
    $surname  = $_POST['w_surname'];
    $position  = $_POST['w__position'];
```

**after these infos, I have my file uploads:**

```
    $userID = $_FILES['user_id']['name'];
    $id_tmp_dir = $_FILES['user_id']['tmp_name'];
    $idSize = $_FILES['user_id']['size'];

    $userTaxCard = $_FILES['user_taxcard']['name'];
    $taxCard_tmp_dir = $_FILES['user_taxcard']['tmp_name'];
    $taxCardSize = $_FILES['user_taxcard']['size'];

    $userAgreement = $_FILES['user_agreement']['name'];
    $agreement_tmp_dir = $_FILES['user_agreement']['tmp_name'];
    $agreementSize = $_FILES['user_agreement']['size'];

    $imgFile = $_FILES['user_image']['name'];
    $img_tmp_dir = $_FILES['user_image']['tmp_name'];
    $imgSize = $_FILES['user_image']['size'];
```

***Currently I have 18 different file upload inputs, with different names***

Now I have the part to upload the files, and for each of those 18 file inputs, I have this block of code which I just repeat and replace the names:

```
  if($_FILES['user_id']['error'] == 0) {

  $upload_dir_id = 'user_id/';

  $idExt = strtolower(pathinfo($userID,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
  $valid_extensions_id = array('pdf'); // valid extensions
  $userid = $name . "-id-" . rand(1000,1000000).".".$idExt;

  if(in_array($idExt, $valid_extensions_id)){

    if($idSize < 5000000)        {

      move_uploaded_file($id_tmp_dir,$upload_dir_id.$userid);
    }
    else{
      $errMSG = "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    }
  }
  }
```

***You can imagine how big the code is***

And this is the last chunk of code:

```
    // if no error occured, continue ....
    if(!isset($errMSG))
    {
        $stmt = $DB_con->prepare('INSERT INTO Radnici2(id, name, surname, position, userTaxCard, userAgreement, imgFile, userID) VALUES(:urid, :uime, :uprezime, :uroditelj, :usprema, :uzdravlje, :uljekarski, :upradnika)');

        $stmt->bindParam(':uid',$id);
        $stmt->bindParam(':uname',$name);    
        $stmt->bindParam(':usurname',$surname);
        $stmt->bindParam(':uposition',$position);;
        $stmt->bindParam(':utaxc',$usertaxc);
        $stmt->bindParam(':uagreement',$useragreement);
        $stmt->bindParam(':upic',$userpic);

        if($stmt->execute())
        {
            $successMSG = "Success";
            header("refresh:3;index.php"); // redirects image view page after 5 seconds.
        }
        else
        {
            $errMSG = "Error....";
        }
    }
```

Is this a valid way to upload files? It doesn't feel that this what I did is correct, or that it can be greatly improved.
Is there any better way?
Thank you.

Comment: For example, you could name your inputs like file1 file2 file3 file4 and then instead of repeating the PHP code 18 times you do a for-loop that counts to 18 and then simply find the pictures by `$file[counter_of_loop]`

Comment: @Twinfriends hmm, yeah. That's a great idea. Thanks for the input